# Error Running dtexec through command line with user input as variable

Tags: batch-file, dtexec

Hi Gys new to batching coding

Need help in executing the below code..

dtexec /server .\DI02UAT /ISserver "\ssisdb\RiskVision\Sub_RiskVison_MKDBData\main.dstx" /Envreference 55 /par "$Serveroption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)";True
/Par "$Package::Applicationcode";"RiskVsion" /Par "$package::Sourcefile";"Dialy_MKDB_ddmmyyy.csv" /Par "$Package::BatchJob";"ERISKVINPUT.SSIS0000010" /Par"$packageage::Asofdate";"mmddyyyy"

for the above code the parameters need to pass manually are EnvreferenceApplication CodeSource file path Batch JobAsOFDate can any one help me out in bulinging new code thank in advance

Comment: I've tried to format your question more appropriately, but have not guessed whether you just had no care and attention, or you really do have the code over multiple lines. Your title states error, but you haven't provided one at all. It also mentions user input and variable, neither of which are indicated anywhere within yuor code or question body. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60884063/edit), and make significant improvements to it, if you'd like us to help you to fix a specific replcable issue with it. Otherwise delete it before it is closed as off topic.

Comment: What is your question ?